# Error message in openpyxl: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'values_only'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am learning openpyxl, the very basic stuffs. I follow only the steps in some online tutorials, but I still got an error messages regarding to "values_only=True". I cannot find where the problem is.. I am using Python 3.6.6 from jupyter.

My codes are:

```
pip install openpyxl

# Create a hello_world.xlsx
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

sheet['A1'] = 'Hello'
sheet['B1'] = 'word!'

workbook.save(filename = 'hello_world.xlsx')

# Read this hello_world.xlsx

from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename = 'hello_world.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active

for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row = 1, 
                           max_row = 2,
                           values_only=True):
    print(value)
```

This error message appears: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'values_only'

Thank you for your help..

Comment: Which version of openpyxl do you have installed?

Comment: @CharlieClark my old openpyxl version was less than 2.6. Now I upgrade to 3.0 and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of openpyxl. The `values_only` argument was only added in version 2.6.

Try to upgrade, `pip install -U openpyxl`.

`.iter_rows` signature in [2.5.14](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.14/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html):

> iter_rows(range_string=None, min_row=None, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None, row_offset=0, column_offset=0)

And in [2.6](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.6/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html):

> iter_rows(min_row=None, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None, values_only=False)

Comment: Yes! my old version was less than 2.6. Now I upgrade to 3.0 and it works! Thank you!!!!